# Toolbar for ArcScan raster painting does not appear in edit session?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, arcscan

I am in an editing session and am trying to vectorize a raster using ArcScan. The raster is a TIFF file (an 8-bit, single band raster with an unsigned integer pixel type). When I select "start clean-up" on the vectorization on the Raster Cleanup toolbar and then select the Raster Painting tool, the tools do not appear.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to obtain the missing toolbar. You find the file called "normal.mxt" and give it a different extension. Reopen ArcMap and the toolbar reappears.